# What's this piece called (Need to know what to stick into Google)?

Tags: kitchens, drawers

I've got a drawer that is held in place with these clip type things but one of them is missing.
I want to try and find a replacement but I need to know what it's called so that I know what to search for on Google.

[image]

Where the one that's missing would be, there's a screw that it would have mounted on to.

[image]

Comment: Small pieces like this are often manufacturer specific.  Do you know the manufacturer (such as IKEA)?  I'd call it a clip or standoff.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the word draw in this context. Can you try to clarify what the pipe pipe/dowel is and where this is located? What is the diameter of the dowel? I might look for a dowel clamp or clip.

Comment: By draw do you mean drawer?

Comment: Draw is probably meant to be drawer, and that would be some from of drawer slide, or drawer slide support; but yes, likely manufacturer specific as well.

Comment: @depperm I've just added another photo, the front of the draw is on the left of the photo. Don't know if I've got any old paperwork with the manufacturer's name on, the kitchen was already in place when I moved in but I believe it came from a shop in the UK called Magnet

Comment: @SolarMike it's probably just the difference between American English and British English

Comment: @SpacePhoenix, I think you're thinking of _drawl_...

Comment: do you want an exact match or would an alternative be ok if it does the job?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - nope. `A box-shaped storage compartment without a lid, made to slide horizontally in and out of a desk, chest, or other piece of furniture` is a [drawer in British English](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/drawer) too.

Comment: I think you need to take better pictures to get an answer.

Comment: Take a picture of the part and do an image search with Google. Google also has the app called Lens. It alows you to take a picture of something and does a Reverse image search. I have had excellent results looking for the name of many different things.

Comment: No luck with the image search, it just came up with wood. I'll have to try and pry one of the remaining ones off of its mounting screw and zoom into it as much as possible